# Winpcap code - Capture loses packets in loop

Tags: c, networking, packet-capture, winpcap

I have a loop to capture packets with pcap_next_ex and in each iteraction I do a lot of functions calls according to process the packets. This stuff can be simulated by a Sleep() call in the loop. Then what happen then I call Sleep in a pcap_next_ex() loop?.

```
pcap_pkthdr* header = NULL;

UCHAR* content = NULL;

pcap = pcap_open(adapterName.c_str(), 65536, PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS, 1000, NULL, NULL);

//Set to nonblock mode?

while (INT res = pcap_next_ex(pcap, &header, const_cast<const UCHAR**>(&content)) >= 0)
{
    if (res != FALSE)
    {
        if (content)
        { 
             //Here i do the stuff which I will simulate with a Sleep() call

             Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen code which uses pcap_next_ex and save the packets in a vector to treat them later with another thread, this method reduces the time of the stuff notably but does not convince me a lot. Shall I use this method?.

I would like to use other winpcap functions which capture packets in "non blocking" mode and call an event for each packet which comes... What is the best method to not lost packets with winpcap?.

Any help will be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: I had the same issue. Instead of process packet_data immediately I pushed packet_data in a queue and processed packet_data in other thread.

Answer (score 2):

WinPcap stores packets it captures into a ring buffer the size of which is limited.
If the number of bytes of packets reach the ring buffer size, the old packets are discarded so that WinPcap can store new packets.

So, you should call `pcap_next_ex` as frequently as possible so that you can get as many packets as possible before they are discarded.

Calling `pcap_next_ex` in a dedicated thread and processing packets in another thread is a good practice because this way can call `pcap_next_ex` the most frequently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to know what do you think about "pcap_loop" or "pcap_dispatch". Can them resolve the problem?. Otherwise as you say I have to call "pcap_next_ex" more frequently or create other thread to process the packets.

Comment: As for as I see the source of WinPcap, the callback passed to `pcap_loop` (or `pcap_dispatch`) is called in the same thread that called the `pcap_loop`, which means you still need a dedicated thread for `pcap_loop` so that it can go back to the work to read the ring buffer as soon as possible.